# How can I control what is sent to workers when using foreach and doMC

Tags: r, parallel-foreach, domc

I do not understand what `foreach` is exporting when using the `doMC` backend.

Is there a way to control what is shipped to the workers ?

The following example seem to suggest that everything in the global environment is shipped, which is causing me trouble when I use 100+ Gb tables.

```
library("foreach")                                                                                                             
library("doMC")                                                                                                                
registerDoMC(3L)                                                                                                               
x <- 1                                                                                                                         
y <- 2                                                                                                                         
foo <- function(x) x+1                                                                                                         
cat(sprintf("hostname: %s, pid: %s, Objects are: %s\n", Sys.getenv("HOSTNAME"), Sys.getpid(), paste(ls(), collapse = ",")))    

foreach(task = 1:3, .noexport = ls()) %dopar%                                                                                  
{                                                                                                                              
    cat(sprintf("hostname: %s, pid: %s, Objects are: %s\n", Sys.getenv("HOSTNAME"), Sys.getpid(), paste(ls(), collapse = ",")))
    foo(task)                                                                                                                  
} -> res                                                                                                                       
print(res)
```

Result: 
**How is foo known to the workers ??**

```
hostname: nyzls604m, pid: 372957, Objects are: foo,res,x,y
hostname: nyzls604m, pid: 385492, Objects are: task       
hostname: nyzls604m, pid: 385493, Objects are: task       
hostname: nyzls604m, pid: 385494, Objects are: task       
[[1]]                                       
[1] 2                                       

[[2]]                                       
[1] 3                                       

[[3]]                                       
[1] 4
```

Comment: `foreach` creates child environments for execution, and `ls` doesn't check enclosing environments. I'm not 100% sure, but I think the exporting mechanism doesn't have an effect when using forks (as `doMC` does), so ecah fork will still see objects from enclosing environments even if you use `.noexport`. What troubles is it causing you? Are you modifying the tables in the forks (thus triggering R's copy-on-modify)?

Comment: No I use 100Gb tables, are you implying that all the forked processes are sharing the objects in memory? I do not think so... FYI I see the same ram used on all processes...

Comment: AFAIK, the whole point of forks is that they share a memory space, though I don't know if R does things in particular. I'm fairly sure the OS knows the forks are childs, so it probably shows the size of the shared memory space for all PIDs.